# Does the series $\sum\frac{3^x}{4^x+1}$ converge or diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does $\frac{3^x}{4^x+1}$ converge or diverge?

I can not think of any methods to determine if this series would converge or diverge. I can not think of a way to integrate it and there are no similar functions that I know their convergence or divergence for.

Comment: Is that a series?

Comment: Yes it is, my bad. I will fix the title

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do a direct comparison test with:

$$\frac{3^x}{4^x}$$

You can rewrite this as:

$$(\frac{3}{4})^x$$

This is a geometric series where r = $\frac{3}{4}$, which converges when $|r|<1$, so now we need to use the direct comparison test.

Because $$\frac{3^x}{4^x} > \frac{3^x}{4^x+1}$$ and $\frac{3^x}{4^x}$ converges, this series converges.

Comment: How did I not see that! Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Approaching it as a function limit and applying L'Hôpital's rule, because it's $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ :

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{3^x}{4^x+1} = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{3^x\ln3}{4^x \ln4} =\lim_{x\to\infty} \bigg(\frac{3}{4}\bigg)^x*\frac{ln3}{ln4} = 0 $$

Comment: This question is about a series, not a sequence convergence.